# What is making the request for tis image file?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I inspect the network activity (using Google Chrome inspector) to serve [this page](http://www.freegold.biz/supreme/) I notice a request for a file named `close.gif` which cannot be found.

The odd thing about this request for a file is first of all that the initiator for the request is listed as "Other" --- in most other cases the initiator is the same domain name as the original request. Next, I grepped [the entire source tree](https://github.com/metaperl/freegold-focus/tree/master/superior) and I cant find `close.gif` anywhere in it.

Any help on identifying what aspect of this static html site is initiating the request for this unknown file is appreciated.

Comment: It's from the adds plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the chrome inspector,
2. click "Elements"
3. hit [Ctrl]+[F]
4. type "close.gif"
5. notice this line:

   ```
   <div id="template04_close" style="display: none; padding: 0px; position: absolute; left: 163px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-image: url(http://www.freegold.biz/supreme/close.gif); cursor: pointer; z-index: 10003; visibility: hidden; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;"></div>
   ```

   especially this part

   ```
   background-image: url(http://www.freegold.biz/supreme/close.gif);
   ```
6. profit from free gold.

Answer (score 0):

It's loaded in from the ads plugin.